# Two Joins in Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

Im trying to make a mysql join statement. I want to join the idRestauraunt of Restauraunts and the idRestauraunt of restaurant_categories. My second join i want to join idCategories of Categories and idCategory of restaurant_categories. The query that I'm trying to use is

```
SELECT distinct r.* from Restaurants  r
JOIN restaurant_categories rc on(r.idRestaurant = rc.idRestaurant )
JOIN Categories c on (c.idCategories =rc.idCategories )
WHERE c.Category ='Pizza Hut'
```

Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'Restaurants'

Categories

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idCategories | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Category     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Restaurants

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idRestaurant | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Password     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Email        | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Number       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

restaurant_categories

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idCategory   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idRestaurant | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: In your query you refer to `Restaurants`, but then you show the schema for a table called `Restauraunts`.  Notice the extra `u` in the latter.

Comment: And ... did that fix the problem?

Comment: no because i had the table name right i just typed it wrong in the question

Comment: There's also no field called `idCategories` in the table `restaurant_categories`, but you try to match against it.

Comment: That distinct is unnecessary as well

Comment: according to the error, you have provided to us not the query that caused the error

Comment: With the tables provided and the query, there shouldn't be any error. We need a little more details to be able to determine the issue.